# String class + operator

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am having this problem where I am trying to overload the add function for my custom string class, so I make a temporary object to add both of the objects lengths and arrays together, however I keep getting segmentation faults and I don't know why.  I have tested both my assignment operator works and my equality operator and they are both perfectly working.

```
myString myString::operator+(const myString& str) const{
int p = 0;
myString tmp;
tmp.sLength = sLength + str.sLength;
tmp.s = new char[tmp.sLength];
while (p != (sLength - 1))
{
    tmp.s[p] =  s[p];

    p++;
}

while (p != (tmp.sLength - 1))
{
    tmp.s[p] = str.s[(p - sLength)];

    p++;    
}


return tmp;
//tmp.s = NULL;
  }
   myString& myString::operator=(const myString& str)
 {
  if (this != &str)
  {
    if ( s != NULL)
    {
        if (str.s == NULL)
        {
            sLength = 0;
            s = NULL;
        }
        else
        {

                delete [] s;

            s = new char [str.sLength];
            sLength = str.sLength;
            for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++)
            s[i] = str.s[i];
        }
    }
}
return *this;   
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is your code compliant with [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: You need to try gdb:  in gdb run the code ('run'), when it faults, climb the stack to code you recognize (using 'up').  Look around this code.  Try "p *this", see the state of your object, or "p localVar"

Answer (score 1):

When this loop

```
while (p != (sLength - 1))
{
    tmp.s[p] =  s[p];

    p++;
}
```

ends its iterations variable `p` will be equal to `sLength -1`.

Thus in this loop

```
while (p != (tmp.sLength - 1))
{
    tmp.s[p] = str.s[(p - sLength)];

    p++;    
}
```

in the first iteration you have

```
    tmp.s[sLength -1] = str.s[(sLength -1 - sLength)];
```

that is

```
    tmp.s[sLength -1] = str.s[(-1)];
                              ^^^^
```

Also it is not clear why the loops use conditions like that `p != sLength - 1`. Why do not they use the conditions like `p != sLength` ?

The copy assignment operator is also wrong.

For example, if s != NULL you just assign to it NULL without deleting the previously allocated memory.

```
if ( s != NULL)
{
    if (str.s == NULL)
    {
        sLength = 0;
        s = NULL;
        ^^^^^^^^
```

And moreover if `s` is equal to `NULL` then you assign to it nothing though `str.s` can be a non null pointer.

Also a question arises why do you use here the following condition in the loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
        s[i] = str.s[i];
```

instead of

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sLength - 1; i++)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        s[i] = str.s[i];
```

as it is in the `operator +`?

Comment: Thanks for the help